# Traccar Web Interface: Where's Last Update Logic to calculate relative time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, extjs, tracking

I've create a web page using Traccar's API using basic HTML, JS/jQuery, and CSS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWSDp.jpg. In this web page I'm displaying some information about a tracking device similar to the information you see in the Traccar's Web Interface:https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Yss.jpg

I'm receiving the device's last update time in a ISO format: 2019-01-11T15:55:47.377+0000 from Traccar's API.

I need to display the relative time between the device's last update and the time I open the web page like the Web interface is doing (even adjusting to my Time Zone) and showing last update 28 days ago, or 1 hour or 10 minutes ago.

Traccar shares the source code for the Web interface https://github.com/traccar/traccar-web but I haven't found where exactly it indicates this logic for Last Update. Which file is it? or what libraries should I use to get the same results? I'm not familiar on ExtJS web apps yet, so if anyone is familiar with these type of web apps, please advise!

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update:** I received some direction from the author of the Traccar software, he directed me to AttributeFormatter.js file inside app folder: https://github.com/traccar/traccar-web/tree/master/web/app So I'm using the lastUpdateFormatter function, but it's output is not correct yet:

Last Update: **NaN minutes**

Comment: So you are not making your app in ExtJS? You just want to write similar app right? Is your app going to be written in JavaScript?

Comment: I've created a simple web page using html, javascript and jquery and css. I just added a screenshot of my web page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to achieve the requirement.

```js
console.log(`Current time -----`, moment().fromNow())

console.log(`From device's last update time ----`, moment('2019-01-11T15:55:47.377+0000').fromNow())
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

You can also use in ExtJS as well. You can check here with working [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2p3l).

**Code Snippet**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {


        function randomDate(start, end) {
            return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
        }

        // Define store
        Ext.define('DataStore', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            alias: 'store.datastore',
            pageSize: 50,

            fields: [
                'title', 'forumtitle', 'forumid', 'username', {
                    name: 'replycount',
                    type: 'int'
                }, {
                    name: 'lastpost',
                    convert: function (v, r) {
                        let date = randomDate(new Date(2018, 0, 1), new Date());
                        return moment(date).fromNow();
                    }
                },
                'lastposter', 'excerpt', 'threadid'
            ],

            remoteSort: true,
            proxy: {
                // load using script tags for cross domain, if the data in on the same domain as
                // this page, an HttpProxy would be better
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: '//www.sencha.com/forum/topics-browse-remote.php',
                reader: {
                    rootProperty: 'topics',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                },
                // sends single sort as multi parameter
                simpleSortMode: true
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'ExtJs Forum',
            store: {
                type: 'datastore'
            },
            autoLoad: true,
            columns: [{
                text: 'Forum Title',
                dataIndex: 'forumtitle',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Last update',
                dataIndex: 'lastpost',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Title',
                dataIndex: 'title',
                flex: 1
            }],
            bbar: {
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                displayInfo: true
            },
            height: 450,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```